# Increment a variable using a Bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a file that contains the following text.

```
//
//  test_file.h
//  test project
//
//  Created by Test User
//

#ifndef test_file_constants_h
#define test_file_constants_h

// Generic includes
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define PF_MASTER_VERSION 3.0.0
#define PF_BUILD_VERSION 1

#endif
```

I need to write a script that can increment the `PF_BUILD_VERSION` by one each time it runs. I've tried looking at [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) and [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) and failed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `awk` based solution could be:

```
awk '/^#define PF_BUILD_VERSION / {$3++} 1' infile >outfile  &&  mv outfile infile
```

Answer (score 5):

A Perl approach:

```
perl -pe 's/^#define PF_BUILD_VERSION \K(\d+)/$1+2/e' file > newfile
```

Or, to edit the file in place:

```
perl -i -pe 's/^#define PF_BUILD_VERSION \K(\d+)/$1+2/e' file
```